# C++ does not support default-int

Tags: c++, class, variables, types, ascii

I am getting an error on my private variables Player_player; and Level _level; it is telling me that it is missing the type specifier and im not sure why this is. I have made classes for both Level and Player, so shouldnt I be able to use Player and Level to specify the variable type?

thanks for the help,

mike

```
//GameSystem.h

#pragma once
#include "Player.h"
#include "Level.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class GameSystem
 {
 public:
    GameSystem(string levelFileName);

    void playGame();

private:
    Level _level;
    Player _player;
  };
```

#

//Player.h

```
  #pragma once
  #include "GameSystem.h"
  #include "Level.h"
  #include <string>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <cstdlib>
  #include <conio.h>
  #include <vector>

  using namespace std;

  class Player
  {
  public:
     Player();

void initPlayer(int level, int health, int attack, int defense, int experience);

    //Setters
void setPosition(int x, int y);

    //Getters
void getPosition(int &x, int &y);


private:

    //Properties
int _level;
int _health;
int _attack;
int _defense;
int _experience;

    //Position
int _x;
int _y;
  };
```

Comment: Could you please include the full error message?

Comment: Psychic debugger says: recursive headers.

Comment: error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '_player'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Comment: Mooing Duck, i think thats because i accidentally labled this as level.h instead of gamesystem.h

Comment: Please edit the question to include the error message. It means `Player` isn't defined at that point. Without seeing Player.h, I cannot say why.

Comment: @MichaelSchroeder 1st: Put additional information by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29520668/edit) please. 2nd: Please don't use leading underscores (`_`) for variable names. These are reserved for standard language implementation defined symbols.

Comment: Does Player.h include GameSystem.h?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve circular dependencies in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c)

Comment: Why does Player.h need to include GameSystem.h?

Comment: I added the Player.h                                                                                 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '_player'                                                                                                                           error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Comment: Please refrain from using leading '_' in variable names, as they may be reserved for compiler usage.  (You could simply remove the character or place it at the end of the identifier.)

Comment: why was i tought that _ was used for pricate variables?

Comment: @MichaelSchroeder: Talk to the person who taught you the coding style, as they would know.

Comment: Are there line numbers associated with your error messages?

Comment: Do you know whay these variables are unspecified?

Comment: Your `Player.h` file doesn't use any of the header files you are including.  Remove them.  Put them in the source file.

Comment: line 22 of GameSystem.h

Comment: Though not the problem: does your player.h file have a #pragma once at the top?  If not you should add one.

Comment: You got to show the cpp file where it all start - that is where the problem can be found. My guess is that GameSystem.h is included before Player.h and Level.h.

Comment: @MichaelSchroeder You should assume that half of what you are taught about C++ programming at a school is either wrong or obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

Your `GameSystem.h` file has the line:

```
#include "Player.h"
```

Your `Player.h` file has the line:

```
#include "GameSystem.h"
```

This can't be good.  And besides the `Player` class declaration in the header file doesn't use anything from `GameSystem.h`, so remove the `GameSystem.h` from the header file (I recommend removing all the `#include` that don't resolve anything in Player.h header file).

**Edit 1:**
I changed the header files and made them use [Include Guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).  I don't get any errors.
Player.hpp:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_HPP
#define PLAYER_HPP
  class Player
  {
  public:
     Player();

void initPlayer(int level, int health, int attack, int defense, int experience);

    //Setters
void setPosition(int x, int y);

    //Getters
void getPosition(int &x, int &y);


private:

    //Properties
int _level;
int _health;
int _attack;
int _defense;
int _experience;

    //Position
int _x;
int _y;
  };

#endif // PLAYER_HPP
```

GameSystem.hpp:

```
#ifndef GSYSTEM_HPP
#define GSYSTEM_HPP

#include "Player.hpp"
#include "Level.hpp"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class GameSystem
 {
 public:
    GameSystem(string levelFileName);

    void playGame();

private:
    Level _level;
    Player _player;
  };

#endif // GSYSTEM_HPP
```

I changed the filename extensions to help distinguish between C language header files (.h) and C++ language header files (.hpp).

I also simplified the header files by remove unused include files.

Comment: Also, remove the `using namespace std;` from the header files.  Your `Player` class doesn't use anything from `namespace std`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a dependency problem here, there are two solutions.

First, Player.h isn't actually dependent on GameSystem.h, so don't include GameSystem.h in Player.h.

```
//Player.h
#pragma once
//Remove GameSystem.h
//#include "GameSystem.h"
#include "Level.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
```

If, for some reason, you DO need the GameSystem class declaration in the Player class, just do this:

```
//Player.h
#pragma once
#include "Level.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>

//Declare the class
class GameSystem;
```

You will need to include the full header file in the .cpp file, but you don't actually need the full class definition to use a class in another classes definition (actually, GameSystem.h doesn't even need to include Player.h, it could just declare but not define the Player class)

Comment: There is a *third* solution, and that is to remove the `#include "GameSystem.h"` from `Player.h`, since the `Player` class doesn't reference `GameSystem`.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews, that's what my 1st solution is

Comment: hint about dependecy problem helped